# durandal compose and virtual elements

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I am trying to use durandal compose to load an external html template like so:

```
<section>
    <!-- ko with: $root.Table -->
    <table class="input-cells" style="overflow-x:scroll;" data-bind="style: {width:Width},css: {alternateGreyRows: AlternateGreyBackgroundRows }">
        <thead data-bind="foreach: HeaderRows">
            <tr data-bind="foreach: Cells">
                <!-- ko compose:{activationData:$data, model:'../indicators/cellstyles'} --><!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Rows">
            <tr data-bind="foreach: Cells">
                <!-- ko compose:{activationData:$data, model:'../indicators/cellstyles'} --><!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

My cellstyles module looks like this HTML:

```
<!-- ko if: data.Style()=='42' -->   <!-- @* simple text cell*@-->
<td data-bind="attr:{colspan:data.ColSpan, rowspan:data.RowSpan},text:data.Model.Name"></td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

JS:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout', 'durandal/global', 'plugins/ajax', 'plugins/formatters'], function (router, ko, global, ajax,formatters) {
    var vm = {};
    vm.formatters = formatters;
    vm.data = {};
    vm.activate = function (data) {
        vm.data = data;
        debugger;
    };

    return vm;
});
```

The knockout containerless/virtual element (if statement) at the root of cellstyles.html however is being ignored (it is not executing and is being treated like a normal HTML comment so the inside of the if is being run always). Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Anyone run into something like this before?

Comment: Not sure if durandal accepts a comment as a root element. Try wrapping cellstyles in a div.

Comment: Your right it doesn't seem to, but since I am building an HTML table, I cannot have a div inside rows and outside the TDs because that is not valid HTML.

Comment: Bracket the <tr> in your virtual if statement and let the <td> stand alone in your composition.  I gather that it's not the <td> that your conditionally displaying, but the <tr>.  The root-level comment is confusing Durandal.

Comment: Have you considered multiple tbody? It is actually valid HTML.

Comment: The cell style is violating Durandal's rule The view has exactly one root element (see http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-View.html). Consider removing the if logic from the view and put it onto the cellstyles view model instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful hints and workarounds everyone, like the multiple tbody suggestion, and doc reference telling me that it can't be used with more than one root element.

Compose is for inserting a module into a page, but can be limiting when used just to insert HTML into a view. For example if you have more than one root element, Durandal does buggy things like stripping out virtual elements, inserting divs where they shouldn't go, etc.

If, like me, your app is considerably more complex than the examples posted here, and you do need to be able to inject HTML exactly where your need it, without putting in additional HTML in places it shouldn't go as a hack/workaround, I recommend you look at the text plugin instead and create a module to go along with your HTML and do everything that way. It's a bit more complex, but is necessary if you need to generate exactly the HTML you need.

Compose does NOT work for the purpose of easily injecting HTML into another HTML file. The text plugin however does seem to work correctly so I'm using that instead to load external HTML then manually inserting it.

Comment: Actually, that's not true.  Compose is _not_ simply for inserting a module into a page.  It can be used to do exactly what you're looking to do, and Durandal uses the text plugin to achieve it.

Comment: I have posted an example above of a situation where it does not work correctly. If you need to insert HTML into another HTML file, compose only works if there is only one root element in the source file. I did not understand your comment above. It is the TD that I was trying to conditionally display (dynamic columns). Each column has different cell types which may contains dropdowns, textareas, text, etc. But this specific example is irrelevant, there are many situations under which people just want to include an HTML file in another, as IS, without arbitrary restrictions. Compose won't do it.

Comment: Just so we are clear: my requirement is to insert ANY html file, AS IS, into ANY other html file. That is what I could not get it to do. I was able to do it if there was only 1 root element, but as I stated above that was too limiting, I had many cases where that didn't cut it.

Comment: Compose allows you to insert any HTML file into any other HTML file, with or without activation data, with or without a viewmodel.  If you compose with just a view, for example, you are injecting your HTML file as is, with no viewmodel behind it.  If you do not pass activation data either, you have inserted any HTML file into any other HTML file.  All HTML files can be single-rooted without changing the intention of multiple roots.

Comment: That is not correct. The documentation links posted in the comments above clearly state (and they are accurate) that you cannot insert an HTML fragment with multiple root elements. If you have multiple root elements it tries to wrap them in a single DIV, which can cause invalid HTML, and even that doesn't work correctly because it strips out virtual elements. I spent many hours on this, and I can say with certainty you should not use compose if you need to insert an html fragment with multiple root elements. In Durandal 2.0.1 there are many bugs in that scenario.

Comment: You claim all HTML files can be single rooted without changing the intention, so how do you single root this: <!DOCTYPE html><html> OR this: <tbody data-bind="foreach:something"></tbody><tbody data-bind="foreach:somethingelse"></tbody> ? There are many examples of legitimate need to do this.

Comment: Bracket your multiple `<tbody>`s in a `<table>`.  The `<table>` is your single root.  As for `<!DOCTYPE>` example, no need.  With Durandal, you're creating a SPA.  The `<!DOCTYPE>` is in your index.html, or index.cshtml, or whatever your server-side language or technology is.

Comment: I'm aware that you cannot insert an HTML fragment with multiple roots.  That's not what I was suggesting.  You'll always be able to single-root, or maneuver out of the problem by moving your composition higher up in the HTML hierarchy.  Again, Durandal uses the text plugin to load HTML fragments..

Comment: Think about what you just said for a second.. so if you have file with multiple TD/THs you suggest to get a single root go to the TR/HR level, but then you realize you can't have multiple TRs either and have to go to the TBODY/THEAD level, soon you end up having to put the entire table into a single huge file... and then you can't reuse your HTML template fragments in another table type! Using that approach you won't have any HTML fragments to insert for an entire table. By the way, I AM using the text plugin, and the text plugin is NOT limited to single root like compose is.

Comment: I get that in some cases you can workaround this, but I still feel that your project design should dictate what your modules/views/fragments need to look like, not the limitations of the compose binding.

Comment: I'm genuinely interested in how this develops for you.  I have many tables that compose row fragments, which I reuse elsewhere.  Same goes for column fragments.  Considering the complexity of our application, I'm not certain why we have not hit on the limitation you're suggesting.  In other words, the issue of multiple roots has never been an issue.  Perhaps we can compare notes later on down the road.

Comment: Your profile says you have components for durandal, I am interested to learn more. I have a large enterprise app also and recently built an excel like grid in plugin, supports scrolling body, mixed fixed&% widths, dynamic everything based off json model, working on calculated columns and grouping rows, etc. My email is enis at dzic.com if you want to touch base.

Comment: That's awesome! Yes, I let Rob Eisenberg know that I intend to release through GitHub a set of Durandal-specific components towards the middle of the year.  He thinks the community could really benefit from it.  Here is a link to a Stack Overflow response I gave concerning multi-view widgets, which includes a link to our DatePicker, one of about 7 components we have so far: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22230756/3174746.  Perhaps we could combine our efforts at some point.  Also, my email is etaylor at tiersoftinc.com.  I've taken note of yours.

Comment: Hey guys, one example of where multiple roots are requires is a recursive rendering of a tree. My tree is required to be rendered as a simple (not nested) <ul>. I cannot figure out how to do it with single root limitation. Question with bounty here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642485/durandal-recursive-composing-of-template